# Why isn't height: 100% working on this div?

Tags: html, css

The question seems simple enough. Like a good little nerd I've done my research. Everything that I've found says that for something to have `height: 100%` every nested parent element must have a height for the child div to fill up. And that's exactly what I have.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's literally all my HTML.  I JUST started this project, which is part of the reason I'm so bewildered. My CSS looks like this:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

That's it.  That's all my code. The background color of `#content` is exclusively so I can see the space it takes up. If I add text in the div or change its height to a pixel value in the CSS, the color shows up. If I switch it back to this, it disappears. Additionally, I'm working in Chrome and when I mouse over source in the Elements tab of the dev tools, both `html` and `body` are very clearly the height of the window. When I mouse over the `#content` div, I can see the style in the dev tools where it says `height: 100%`, but the height is 0px. I'm beyond perplexed. Any ideas?

Comment: div height = div contents, so no contents = 100% height of 0. add a min-height using px to have a constant coloured div

Comment: The body has a height of `auto`, the div has a height of `100%`, `100%` of `auto` is `auto`

Comment: @Quentin the body has a height of `100%`, I set it manually.

Comment: @ElleNolan body has a `min-height` - not `height`, `height` will still be `auto`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs If that's the case, is it even possible to make a div that tall? I wanted `min-height: 100%` but if it will only stretch as far as its contents then this is an exercise in futility. Is there a solution to my problem with flexbox or something?

Comment: Which browser aer you using? The color is shown successfully for IE11 and Chrome 45

Comment: @Quentin So how would I go about creating a div with a `min-height` equal to 100% of the screen without setting `body { height: 100%; }`? Because I don't want to do that since it messes with everything if the page scrolls down - overflow ends up being outside `body`. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @ElleNolan — https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

Comment: @Mumrah81 We're on Chrome 69 my man.

Comment: @ElleNolan you can use `height: 100vh` but it's really not what you want, if you want the whole body to be full height, target the body, not a child div

Comment: I'm gonna take a gander at what Quentin sent me, that holy grail crap.  It should get done what I need.  Thank you though!

Comment: using "height: 100vh;" viewport-height will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the `body` elementy, you need a "real" `height`setting -  `min-height: 100%;` isn't sufficient as a reference for a relative child element height setting. So change `min-height: 100%;` to `height: 100%;`  there.

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S.: Your closing `<body>` tag was lacking the  `/` character - I changed that to `</body>` in your code

Comment: The lack of </body> was simply an error in me manually typing up the code into SE.  And I wanted to avoid that because setting the body's height to a hard 100% can have unintended side effects if the page has overflow and needs vertical scroll.  It messes with CSS and other crap.  So your solution does work and if nobody answers anything better I'll accept it, even though it's not exactly what I was going for.  Thanks!

Comment: You can add `overflow: visible` to `body`, then it will expand and scroll (within HTML) if needed.

Comment: In my experience it still scrolls fine, it just has stylistic side-effects that are difficult to predict and remedy.  Adding gaps place and such.  Plus it messes with `window.scrollTo` in JavaScript, which I use for sinusoidal scroll animations.